# Update text in TextBox from Async button click

Tags: asynchronous, webforms

I have a process that takes a long time to finish executing, the user should be able to see a simple feedback when the process starts and finishes
something like this:

```cs
    protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Process started..\n";
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        await ProcessDelay();

        sw.Stop();

        TextBox1.Text += "Process finished.\n";
        TextBox1.Text += "Elapsed Time (ms): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "\n";
    }

    private async Task ProcessDelay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
```

Text value in TextBox is not updated until the execution of ProcessDelay() is done. What am I missing here?

Comment: Works as expected for me

Comment: `Process started..   
Process finished.   
Elapsed Time (ms): 5004`

Comment: @NedStoyanov Did you see "Process started" just when you clicked the button or the whole text was printed out at once?

Comment: When I clicked the button

Comment: @NedStoyanov I know it's working in the background like stop watch is counting, but i wanna see "Process started" in the text box first thing, not all the text at once. the real method takes up to 2 minutes and there's no way user will know it's working for real unless i show something in the text box.

Comment: when I clciked the button I saw the text `Process started..`, then after 5 seconds the text `Process finished. Elapsed Time (ms): 5004` is appended to the textbox

Comment: @NedStoyanov this is strange!! is there anything i should do in aspx file other than adding Async="true" ?

Comment: I was using WinForms! Have a look at this blog for asp http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when you're working with ASP.NET, you are working within a strict request+response paradigm. WebForms tries to hide this from you, but it's still one-response-per-request underneath. So, when you click a button in your browser, it sends a request to the web server, which executes the click code, returning a result. It can only return one result. So there's no way it can, say, make a change to part of the page and then later make another change.

To put it another way, `async` on ASP.NET yields to the ASP.NET runtime (that is, it returns the request thread to the thread pool). It does *not* yield to the browser (that is, it does not return a response).

To do what you want, you'll need an alternative technology. If the background work doesn't take too long, you could consider SignalR. Otherwise, you'll probably need a proper distributed architecture: a reliable queue connected to an independent background process. I describe a few approaches [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).